# vue.config.js: Unresolved variable or type module => a php file can't be found

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, phpstorm

I am trying to fetch some data from a database via a php-file. When I try to load the data I get the following error message in the browsers console: “GET http://localhost:8080/api/call_evm.php 404 (Not Found)”.

This is the corresponding method:

```
methods: {
    lade_daten: function () {
        let vm = this;
        $.getJSON("/api/call_evm.php", function(result){
            vm.datas = result;
        });
    }
},

mounted(){
    this.lade_daten();
}
```

My vue.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost/evm-formular/api',
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/api': ''
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.externals({
            jquery: 'jQuery',
            select2:'select2'
        })
    }
}
```

When I hover the mouse arrow over the keyword module I get the following tooltip:
“Unresolved variable or type module”

What does it mean?
What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: these problems are unrelated. `Unresolved variable or type module` error means that the IDE can't find a javascript library where `module` is defined, it will go away if you enable **Coding assistance for Node.js** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**. But this won't help with your runtime error that is caused by your application setup

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The tooltip disappeared. The keyword module is grey while the rest of the code is violett. I guess its a sign for the problem, but i don't know what it means...

Comment: Now I got another problem: when calling http://localhost:8080/formular1 I got this error message:
“vue-router.esm.js:1897 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined”

I installed jQuery in the project via NPM.

Do you have any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: maybe it's not properly imported in your code?